# not all trait items implemented, missing: `score_update_worst_case`

Tags: runtime-upgrade, try-runtime

I am unable to build `try-runtime` features.

My command: `cargo build --features try-runtime --release`

My issue:

```
 impl<T: Config> SortedListProvider<T::AccountId> for UseValidatorsMap<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `score_update_worst_case` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn score_update_worst_case(_: &<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, _: bool) -> <Self as frame_election_provider_support::SortedListProvider<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Score { todo!() }`

impl<T: Config> SortedListProvider<T::AccountId> for UseNominatorsAndValidatorsMap<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `score_update_worst_case` in implementation
```

`runtime/Cargo.toml`

`pallet-staking = { workspace = true }`

```
runtime-benchmarks =[

  ...
  pallet-staking/runtime-benchmarks
  ...

]
```

```
try-runtime = [

...
pallet-staking/try-runtime

...

]
```